# How to save file through Mojo by Maven?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, pom.xml, maven-plugin

I need to save a text file as an artifact in jenkins folder and took the sample code's own apache.

Code plugin:

```
package sample.plugin;

/*
 * Copyright 2001-2005 The Apache Software Foundation.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

import org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractMojo;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException;

import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.LifecyclePhase;
import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.Mojo;
import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.Parameter;
import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.ResolutionScope;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Goal which touches a timestamp file.
 *
 *
 */
@Mojo( name = "touch", defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.PROCESS_SOURCES )
public class MyMojo
    extends AbstractMojo
{
    /**
     * Location of the file.
     */
    @Parameter( defaultValue = "${project.build.directory}", property = "outputDirectory", required = true )
    private File outputDirectory;

    public void execute()
        throws MojoExecutionException
    {
        getLog().info("Mensagem de Log - Ricardo!!!");
        File f = outputDirectory;

        if ( !f.exists() )
        {
            f.mkdirs();
        }

        File touch = new File( f, "touch.txt" );

        FileWriter w = null;
        try
        {
            w = new FileWriter( touch );

            w.write( "touch.txt" );
        }
        catch ( IOException e )
        {
            throw new MojoExecutionException( "Error creating file " + touch, e );
        }
        finally
        {
            if ( w != null )
            {
                try
                {
                    w.close();
                }
                catch ( IOException e )
                {
                    // ignore
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

pom.xml file plugin:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>sample.plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>hello-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
    <packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>

    <name>hello-maven-plugin Maven Plugin</name>

    <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
            <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <goalPrefix>hello-maven-plugin</goalPrefix>
                    <skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>true</skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-descriptor</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>descriptor</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>help-descriptor</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>helpmojo</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>           

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                    only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>
                                            org.apache.maven.plugins
                                        </groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            maven-plugin-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                            [3.2,)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>helpmojo</goal>
                                            <goal>descriptor</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore></ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>run-its</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-invoker-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.7</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <debug>true</debug>
                            <cloneProjectsTo>${project.build.directory}/it</cloneProjectsTo>
                            <pomIncludes>
                                <pomInclude>*/pom.xml</pomInclude>
                            </pomIncludes>
                            <postBuildHookScript>verify</postBuildHookScript>
                            <localRepositoryPath>${project.build.directory}/local-repo</localRepositoryPath>
                            <settingsFile>src/it/settings.xml</settingsFile>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>clean</goal>
                                <goal>test-compile</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>integration-test</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>install</goal>
                                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                    <goal>verify</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

pom.xml file of the test project that uses the plugin:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>exemplo.utilizacao.plugin.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>teste</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>teste</name>
    <description>teste</description>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>sample.plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>hello-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDir>${project.basedir}</outputDir> <!-- this will create touch.txt at the root of the project -->                
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>touch</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                    only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>sample.plugin</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            hello-maven-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                            [1.0-SNAPSHOT,)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>sayhi</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore></ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

Jenkins directory guided by environment variables which need to save the text file:

```
 jenkins_home/jobs/myapp/builds/build_number/myapp$myapp/archive/myapp/directory
```

My touch.txt file from my plugin was saved at the root of the target folder of my project and I want to save it in jenkins directory specified above.

How must I do to save the text file in the folder jenkins correctly? Should I specify the path in pom.xml file from my test project?

Comment: I can't speak for others, but I don't really see in your question what your actual problem is. You spend a lot of time showing what you have, and very little time explaining what the problem with it is.

Comment: Hello Gimby, thanks for your advice, I'll be more careful. In fact the touch.txt file from my plugin was saved in the root of the target folder of my test project and I want to save it in jenkins directory specified above.

Answer (score 0):

I sounds as if your plugin behaves as expected, outputting into the target directory. This is fine, even desired.

Your question should probably be; How can I get Jenkins to copy a file from an artifacts target directory to a location where I want it installed? This can be done as a build step, but is better answered by someone else than me.